# Serializing generic types using Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have written my own serializer using Jackson. It takes a variable or class and returns a value of any simple type.

Example: serialize(new MyClass(2.0)) will return a double with value 2.0 where MyClass looks as follows:

```
public class MyClass {
  private double number;

  public MyClass(double number) {
    this.number = number;
  }

  @JsonValue
  public double getNumber() {
    return number;
  }
}
```

So to get the correct value I need to set @JsonValue, however, when I serialize an object such as UUID, which not not have the @JsonValue annotation, it returns the expected UUID string.

Creating my own class sans the @JsonValue annotation does not have the same effect. In this case serialize(new MayClass(2.0)) returns the map {"number":2.0} where MyClass looks as follows:

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable, Comparable<MyClass> {
  private double number;

  public MyClass(double number) {
    this.number = number;
  }

  public double getNumber() {
    return number;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(MyClass obj) { return 0; }
}
```

My question is, why does UUID (and other pre-defined serializable classes) serialize as expected, but my own serializable classes do not? Also, how do I get my serializable classes to serialize correctly?

Comment: I think your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432761/serialize-class-with-generic-to-json-using-jackson

Comment: That solution still requires the use of an annotation. Specifically in that case @JsonSerialize. Classes such as UUID and URI (these are just the ones I use, but it applies for all Serializable and Comparable classes) serialize to the correct String (instead of a map) with absolutely no use of Json related annotations. This is the behaviour I need to replicate.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson has predefined UUID, URI, Date, etc. serializers and deserializers, so annotations are not necessary.

If you would like to serialize your class without annotations, you will need to write a custom serializer and deserilizer. eg MyClassSerializer.